# layout.xml update ignored after magento update to 2.0.3/2.0.4

Tags: magento2, layout-update, magento-2.0.4

After my update to magento version 2.0.3 and 2.0.4 my layout-updates in `../htdocs/app/design/frontend/[]/[]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` won't work anymore.

I checked xml structure and checked against `.xsd` files and have no error there.

Any idea what this could cause?